# If pipe returns the same result as previous time, the component is not updated

Tags: angular

In order to explain the issue I created the following Plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/7LO2ylQpObhby9HaUGci

There is a simple pipe that returns 'Yes' if the length of the passed string is greater than 5, otherwise returns 'No'.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'lengthMoreThan5'
})
export class LengthMoreThan5 implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string) {
      console.log('pipe ->', value)
      return value.length > 5 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }
}
```

and in the component template, there is and Input with one way binding like this:

```
<input (blur)="onBlur($event)" [ngModel]="selectedValue | lengthMoreThan5" />
```

The value of the selectedValue property is updated in the onBlur event:

```
onBlur(evt) {
  this.selectedValue = evt.target.value;
}
```

The issue is that if the pipe returns the same result as previous time, the input text would not change.

So, if I put '123456' in the text box and leave, it changes to Yes, which is correct. Now if I come back to the text box and enter '123456' again and leave, this time it does not change.

**Edit:**
I created another Plunkr to explain the issue better, I hope :)
https://plnkr.co/edit/PenjwfTCXlg4uB8f6mfl

Comment: Hmmmm... why should it change if you literally say it **does not** change?

Comment: my expectation is that every time the use enters something in the text box and leave it, to show 'Yes' or 'No' depending on the length of the text.

Comment: Yeah I get it, but if it already shows 'Yes', why should it change to 'No' if the value is still longer than 5?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it well. First it is 'No'. Then I enter '123456' and leave it. It turns to 'Yes'. Then I change it to '999999'. Now it stays '99999' instead of displaying 'Yes'

Comment: Ah, okay, now I get it. To be honest, messing up with the `ngModel` like that (using pipes for an instance) is not the best idea. `NgModel` is async, and with this thing you also violate the principle of single responsibility - now your model is not only responsible for representing the value, but also for formatting it

Comment: I think your problem is that the result of the pipe transform did not change from the previous value. So, when Angular does its check to see if a value changed it does an equality on the previous string and this string and you get no change so it doesn't do anything

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel You are right, wondering if there is any workaround for that.

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan, it is specifically for ngModel. If you change [ngModel] to [value], it has the same behavior.

Comment: I think that you would find this to be an incorrect usage of model binding. If you need to do transformation/processing of your model it should be done in either the `ngModelChange` method or in one of the browser input events like your `blur` usage.

Comment: The closest I could get to displaying as you wanted is this. You'll have to give more details about what you are ultimately trying to do in order to help any more: https://plnkr.co/edit/GhND3zn6pnd8ZLtkwwVM?p=preview

Comment: I really appreciate your response. However, I only need model to get updated on blur, so [(ngModel)] is not an option. I tried to simplify my use case by providing this. I will do my best to create a better sample that can show what I am looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166824/discussion-between-reza-and-daniel-w-strimpel).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your question is about pipe and so on...

But you could do what you want like this:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input #inp (blur)="onBlur($event)"/>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('inp') selectedValue: ElementRef;
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  onBlur(evt) {
    this.selectedValue.nativeElement.value = this.checkValue(evt.target.value);
  }

  checkValue(value) {
    return value.length > 5 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It could be done without pipe.

Here is plnkr: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/OZEDq1T21MaJnY54yCql?p=preview

ps: please don't downgrade if i did not guess what you want )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up doing some similar solution for now, but my question was mostly to see if it can be done with pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

The only solution that worked for me was to have both one way data binding with the pipe for the input element and updating the value of the input in the component onBlur event.

```
onBlur(evt) {
  this.selectedValue = evt.target.value;
  this.inputEl.nativeElement.value = this.lengthMoreThan5Pipe.transform(this.selectedValue);
}
```

I edited the Plnkr here to demonstrate both problem and the solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/PenjwfTCXlg4uB8f6mfl